# Mudar HTTP User Agent

Tags: android

Quando um app Android envia um post para um servido Web (tipo para uma página PHP), esta página recebe um HTTP-UserAgent tipo "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (Java 1.4)".

Quero saber se tem um solução para alterar esta valor do lado Android? O objetivo seria impedir outra app tentar ligar-se nesta pagina. Asim, com um valor especifico, seria possível para o PHP testar quem chama ele.

Comment: Se o objetivo é impedir outros acessos que não sejam feitos pelo App, acredito que você pode enviar um parâmetro extra de cabeçalho sem mudar o `User-Agent`. Para isso, depende de qual classe você está utilizando para realizar a conexão.

Comment: Você deve estar utilizando o [HttpClient da Apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/). Mas que dá, até que dá para alterar o UserAgent, como demonstrado [aqui na documentação](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/preference-api.html). Mas para os fins que você está querendo utilizar acredito que não seja a melhor opção, pois pelo que entendi você quer fazer umas especie de "Autenticação" validando esse campo no servidor, não vou lhe indicar nada, mas se pesquisar um pouco sobre segurança irá ver que esse não é o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de na tua pergunta dares a entender que pretendes limitar o uso do PHP a uma aplicação em particular, onde para o efeito deverias implementar um sistema de autenticação, segue como passar uma [UA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) personalizada:

```
private String url = "http://example.com/";
private String ua = "A minha UA toda bonita";

private HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("User-Agent", ua);
```

Comment: Legal, vou testar isso. Obrigado.